# Pytest does not execute conftest.py

Tags: python, pytest

Pytest does not execute conftest.py when `src/__init__.py` is present in the project structure and `requirements.txt` is installed in a virtual environment.
If I delete `src/__init__.py` then conftest.py is executed as expected.
If I have I use a virtual environment with only pytest installed then conftest.py is executed as expected.
If I install each pip package individually then conftest.py is executed as expected.

After a few hours this is the most minimal example I could come up with to reproduce the issue.

```
|-- src
|   `-- __init__.py
`-- test
    `-- conftest.py
```

Contents of `conftest.py`:

```py
print("test_string")
```

Step to reproduce:

```bash
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
pyenv install 3.11.6
pyenv virtualenv 3.11.6 test
pyenv activate test
pip install -r requirements.txt
pytest > test.log
if [[ $(grep -c test_string test.log) -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Conftest not executed"
fi
pyenv deactivate
pyenv virtualenv-delete -f test
sudo apt-get remove libpq-dev
```

Contents of `requirements.txt`:

```
ansi2html==1.8.0
blinker==1.7.0
certifi==2023.11.17
cfgv==3.4.0
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
click==8.1.7
contourpy==1.2.0
coolname==2.2.0
cycler==0.12.1
dash==2.14.2
dash-bootstrap-components==1.5.0
dash-core-components==2.0.0
dash-dangerously-set-inner-html==0.0.2
dash-html-components==2.0.0
dash-leaflet==1.0.15
dash-table==5.0.0
distlib==0.3.7
dnspython==2.4.2
docker==7.0.0
email-validator==2.1.0.post1
exceptiongroup==1.2.0
filelock==3.13.1
Flask==3.0.0
Flask-WTF==1.2.1
fonttools==4.46.0
greenlet==3.0.1
gunicorn==21.2.0
identify==2.5.32
idna==3.6
importlib-metadata==7.0.0
importlib-resources==6.1.1
iniconfig==2.0.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
joblib==1.3.2
kiwisolver==1.4.5
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
matplotlib==3.8.2
nest-asyncio==1.5.8
nodeenv==1.8.0
numpy==1.26.2
packaging==23.2
pandas==2.1.3
Pillow==10.1.0
platformdirs==4.1.0
plotly==5.18.0
pluggy==1.3.0
pre-commit==3.5.0
psycopg2==2.9.9
pyparsing==3.1.1
pytest==7.4.3
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-dotenv==1.0.0
pytz==2023.3.post1
PyYAML==6.0.1
requests==2.31.0
retrying==1.3.4
scikit-learn==1.3.2
scipy==1.11.4
seaborn==0.13.0
six==1.16.0
SQLAlchemy==2.0.23
tenacity==8.2.3
threadpoolctl==3.2.0
tomli==2.0.1
typing_extensions==4.8.0
tzdata==2023.3
urllib3==2.1.0
virtualenv==20.25.0
Werkzeug==3.0.1
WTForms==3.1.1
xycmap==1.0.1
zipp==3.17.0
```

Can anybody reproduce this issue? And if so, what is the cause of this issue?

Comment: Are you trying to emulate the [src layout](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/src-layout-vs-flat-layout/)? If so, `src` should not directly have `__init__.py` in it. Try following the examples in [Pytest - Choosing a test layout](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/explanation/goodpractices.html#choosing-a-test-layout).

Comment: No I want to use a flat layout. I should have named the folder `app` instead of `src`. But it does not make any difference. Even if you `mv src app` the result is the same. And with `rm app/__init__.py` it works again.